# How to fit textarea exactly inside a div - CSS

Tags: css

I have a `<div>` with fixed width and height (may be in px / %). I have a `<textarea>` inside that, having a width of 100%, like;

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    background: red;
}
textarea{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

But the `</textarea>` is stretching out of the container, like;
[image: Screenshot]

I want the textarea to stretch to 100% with of the container. How can I achieve this?

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/BwVQZ/)** is the working fiddle.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Add `box-sizing:border-box` to the textarea's CSS.

Comment: Firefox is trailing way behind on this one. Try also adding `-moz-box-sizing:border-box`

Comment: @MichaelTheriot I naively thought that if IE8 supported it, Firefox would at least be out of the prefixing stage. That said, IE10 support transform, animation, transition, gradients and so on while Chrome's still blundering around with prefixes... It completely throws off my principle of "if it works in IE without hax then it works in all browsers" that has been true for many years...

Comment: This only fits it in width though, not in height?

Answer (score 13):

You can use box-sizing.  But each browser is different, so this example works for all class A browsers.

```
textarea{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BwVQZ/7/

Answer (score 6):

The textarea has native padding and border.

If you set :

```
textarea{
   height: 100px;
   width: 98%;
   padding:1%;
   border:none;
}
```

It will be fitted :)

Comment: I know this workaround. But the question is not for a solution like this.

Comment: What browser do you have ? The solution of Kolink it's okay for me ;)
maybe you have to add browser prefixes 
‘-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;‘